# Best way to store multiple user-inputted values (port numbers) in Django?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-forms

I'm new to Django and database operations and somewhat intermediate with Python.

I'm building a web app in Django where the user inputs a port number (values between 1 - 65535), but can input multiple port numbers. I'm using the default SQLite DB. The pseudocode is as follows:

1. User enters a valid port number and hits enter
2. The port number is assigned to the model and field name (e.g., ***outbound_firewall_ports***) and is reflected in the web app
3. The user can continue entering additional port number if needed

I have the following field assigned to my class' model:

```
outbound_firewall_ports = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(65535)])
```

Is the best way to get this done using the code above, in combination with forms/views/widgets, or is there another option I should use to essentially create an array from the ***outbound_firewall_ports*** that are then stored in the SQLite DB?

Comment: It sounds like you're too focused on getting all the moving parts working together, that your [data model](https://www.guru99.com/data-modelling-conceptual-logical.html) may be suffering. Could show the Django model for where the field is in? I'm guessing this should be a firewall, so you have a Rule model? Port model? Action model?

Comment: @Melvyn, you hit the nail on the head. I'm trying to scope this out in my data model and am getting a little confused. In my data model, I created a separate class for ports and expected a ManyToMany relationship, but feel like I may be over-complicating it. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/vLEcDUZ) is the data model I created, but am thinking I should scope out the Ports class if I can accomplish creating an array of integers via Forms/Widgets? Or does have a separate Ports class make sense?

Answer (score 1):

So one common mistake is called premature optimization: things seem to be overkill and you try to simplify early on.

The primary distinction for a one-to-many relation or a "compound field" is whether you need to search for one of the many. For a firewall, it's logical that if an incoming request is on ip X port Y that it needs to search for rules that match these two. So a to-many relationship is the better option here.

Now, with the advent of [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield), that on some databases is fully searchable inside the database, this distinction becomes a little blurred.

In this case, I would favour the JSONField, because the port data is not complex, not deeply nested so that it's a datamodel by itself and doesn't require in-database calculations. Your validator will need a little more attention, but other then that, I'd say it's a textbook example for what you could use JSONField for.

For the relationship approach, the logic is pretty simple:

For each port you receive:

```py
config = Config.objects.get(account_username=request.user.username)  # let's assume we are inside a view
port = request.POST.get('port', 0)
if port:
    config.outbound_firewall_ports.add(port)
```

For json it's a little more complex:

```py
config = Config.objects.get(account_username=request.user.username)  # let's assume we are inside a view
port = request.POST.get('port', 0)
if port:
    current_ports = config.outbound_firewall_ports  or [] # type: list
    current_ports.append(port)
    config.outbound_firewall_ports = current_ports
    config.save()
```